# Is Terraform the official Infrastructure as code solution for IBM Cloud?

Tags: terraform, ibm-cloud, infrastructure-as-code, terraform-provider-ibm

Every major cloud provider like AWS or Google Cloud provide their own solutions for infrastructure as code (cloud formation, cloud deployment management).
As far as I am aware IBM used to have its own solution but now all I see is on Terraform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That observation seems correct, [IBM Cloud settled on Terraform](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/terraform?topic=terraform-getting-started) to provide automation for deploying resources.

You need to set up the [IBM Cloud provider for Terraform](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/terraform?topic=terraform-setup_cli), [configure and then you can deploy resources](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/terraform?topic=terraform-configure_provider). Details on the different resources and how to specify them can be found in the [IBM Cloud Provider for Terraform docs](https://ibm-cloud.github.io/tf-ibm-docs/v0.17.1/).